# Eclipse PyTest runfiles.py: error: unrecognized arguments: --verbosity

Tags: python, eclipse, pytest

I am trying to setup pytest on Eclipse and I get the following error

> usage: runfiles.py [options] [file_or_dir] [file_or_dir] [...]
>   runfiles.py: error: unrecognized arguments: --verbosity   inifile:
>   None   rootdir: D:\EclipseWorkspace\SeleniumPyTest\PyTestSelenium

I have con
I am not looking for an alternative IDE I only want to use Eclipse.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I did on mac.
Go to "Preferences"
After that "PyDev"
Go to "PyUnit"
Select "Py.test runner"
In the text field "Parameters for test runner" delete key "--verbosity 0"
Also you can delete this key then setup debug or runner config for your test:
"Edit configuration"
"python unittest"
select your config
go to "arguments"
check "override PyUnit"
and delete key "--verbosity 0"